# What machine instance to use for running GPU workloads in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run Elasticsearch BERT application and would like to understand the minimal configuration for fine-tuning the model using GPU. What machine configuration should I be using?

Reference github: [Fast-Bert](https://github.com/kaushaltrivedi/fast-bert)

Comment: Just in case GCP is not mandatory, check out [vast.ai](https://vast.ai/console/create/)

Answer (score 4):

You would probably need to attach different GPUs to your compute instance to test performance. The `Tesla T4` is the cheapest, while the [Tesla V100](https://cloud.google.com/compute/gpus-pricing) is the most expensive.

The `n1-highmem` or the `n1-highcpu`  families of compute instance would be a good place to start.

Some of the specs published by Google:
[image]