# What image should I use if I need to use NVidia v100 GPU on an instance running on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, nvidia

What image should I use if I need to use NVidia v100 GPU on an instance running on Google Cloud

Listing versions: [listing-versions](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images#listing-versions)

Refer: [nvidia-v100](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/data-center/v100/)

Comment: Does this question help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526950/what-machine-instance-to-use-for-running-gpu-workloads-in-google-cloud-platform

Comment: @AdiDembak nope, I need t run this from deep learning vm and it should compatible with nvidia-v100

Comment: The latest publicly available DLVM image support V100 and all of the released GPUs.

Comment: You just need to reference 'latest' when creating a DLVM instance and you're good to go.
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images#deciding

Comment: Let me know if it has worked for you or if you still need help on this.